# Allow fullscreen for embedded YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request, videos, youtube

Currently, embedded YouTube videos don't allow you to fullscreen them. Clicking the button shows the frustrating message

> Fullscreen is unavailable

An example [answer on different site with an embedded video](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33502) (embedding isn't enabled here on Meta Stack Exchange).

It looks like this is really easy to fix, see for example https://www.allowfullscreen.com/youtube. Could this be enabled?

Comment: This probably works differently for different browsers. On FF Android I have no button, but the title appears; clicking on that takes me to YT where I have all controls enabled.

Comment: @Rob you have to first play the video, only then the button will appear.

Answer (score 4):

As always, user script to the rescue:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Stack Exchange: Fullscreen YouTube
// @grant    none
// @run-at   document-start
// @match    https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match    https://*.superuser.com/*
// @match    https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match    https://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match    https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match    https://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match    https://stackapps.com/*
// @exclude  https://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://area51.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://contests.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude  /^https?:\/\/winterbash\d{4,}\.stackexchange\.com\//
// ==/UserScript==

const SELECTOR = 'iframe[src*="youtube"]';

const fixupNode = node => {
  if (!node.matches?.(SELECTOR))
    return;

  const src = new URL(node.src);
  if (!/(^|\.)youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com$/.test(src.host))
    return;
  
  node.allowFullscreen = true;
};

const fixupUnder = node => {
  fixupNode(node);
  for (const subnode of node.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR))
    fixupNode(subnode);
}

if (document.body)
  fixupUnder(document.body);

new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  for (const mut of mutations) {
    switch (mut.type) {
      case 'attributes':
        fixupNode(mut.target);
        break;
      case 'childList':
        fixupUnder(mut.target);
        break;
    }
  }
}).observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['src'],
  subtree: true,
});
```

Comment: Nitpicking, the last `@exclude` is obsolete, winter bash is no more.

Comment: Winter Bash is no more, but the edition sites are still up, and they are not Q&A sites. So, not obsolete.